# Tags in hot questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add tags next to the question in list of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113664/add-tags-next-to-the-question-in-list-of-questions)

I look at the hot questions a lot from the stack exchange drop down in the top left of every site.

I think a list of some of the tags on the question could give more info about the question before you click on it.

Sometimes I see a question that looks interesting or that I might be able to answer, then after I click on it, It wasn't exactly what I thought it was. The title wasn't bad just had a bit of ambiguity that the tags would have narrowed.

A couple examples:

- A question about programming that doesn't reveal in the title what
  langauge they are asking about
- A question about a video games that doesn't say in the title what
  game they are referring to

Comment: I suggest the tag is added to the front like the title of questions, and all (or the rest) of the tags are added as tooltips.

Comment: and [Can we prepend a tag to questions shown in the “hot questions” tab of the Stack Exchange™ SuperCollider MultiDropdown™?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115432)